# Sweet Alert works in local but Doesn't work in server

Tags: sweetalert

That function works in local host(I am using Laragon) but in the host(Natro) doesn't work. I didn't understandt how is it possible.

```
    $.ajax({
      url:"netting/process.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:new FormData(this),
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      success:function(data){
        veri=JSON.parse(data);
        if (veri.status=="success") {
          swal(veri.head,veri.message,veri.status);
        }
        else{
          swal(veri.head,veri.message,veri.status);
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i also have this problem right now. it work fine in local but gave me error on my hosting.

EDIT: try to use sweetalert2 script bro
i just figured it out by updating my script's src with this https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.26.9/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js

hope it work

Comment: A link-only answer is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question but maybe it will help someone: **Just import JS and CSS separately** like that

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'

import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss'
```

instead of

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
```